# ASP.NET MVC3 System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations -- can an annotation determine the class it is validating?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I am using an `Extended Validation` attribute to turn on stricter validation depending on how I am editing a record.

EG: I have a Parent which has children objects.

When Editing a Child, `ModelState.isValid` is `false`, due to the parent missing, e.g a first name, because I am selecting its parent by `ID` only.

When I edit a Parent -- I want these fields to be required, but not when editing e.g a child and the associated parent is part of what makes up the child.

I have the following code:

```
public class Parent
{
    [Required]        
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }


    [ExtendedValidationRequired(typeof(Parent))]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    ....}
```

And the following for validation:

```
public static class ExtendedValidation
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, bool> extendedValidationExemptions = new Dictionary<Type, bool>();


    /// <summary>
    /// Disable extended validation for a specific type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    public static void DisableExtendedValidation(Type type)
    {
        extendedValidationExemptions[type] = true;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Clear any EV exemptions
    /// </summary>
    public static void Reset()
    {
        extendedValidationExemptions.Clear();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if a class should perform extended validation
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool IsExtendedValidationEnabled(Type type)
    {
        if (extendedValidationExemptions.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}






[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]

public class ExtendedValidationRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{


    private Type _type;
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute
    //     class.
    public ExtendedValidationRequiredAttribute(Type type)
    {
        _type = type;
    }



    // Summary:
    //     Checks that the value of the required data field is not empty.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   value:
    //     The data field value to validate.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     true if validation is successful; otherwise, false.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationException:
    //     The data field value was null.
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (ExtendedValidation.IsExtendedValidationEnabled(_type))
        {
            return base.IsValid(value);
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }


    }




}
```

Is there any way I can get around passing the type explicitly into the validator? I want to be able to enable/disable these validation attributes programmatically.

For example, if I am editing a Child, but a Parent's `[Required]` fields would cause me to have problems, I would disable `typeof(Parent)` in the `extendedValidator`, and then  Validation should work OK. I am just worried about performance impact with all the `typeof()` going on.

My problem that this attempts to address is when I am editing a class such as

```
public class Child
{

   [Required]
   public virtual int id {get;set;}

   [Required]
   public virtual Parent parent {get;set;}

   ....
}
```

My form just has the Parent `ID` (that is all that is needed in my EF or hibernate app), but it will not validate unless the Parent passed in the form has all of the required fields -- which is rather wasteful.

Comment: Why are you passing a parent object to the controller action when editing a child?

Comment: Let me use a clearer example: I have a Car class which has a public virtual Manufacturer manufacturer. That manufacturer class has a required name , address, phone number, etc. Because my Car has a member called Manufacturer. When I call ModelState.IsValid -- because the mfr doesnt have a name, address, etc in my form submit, it fails. I only need the manufacturer ID to perform my Car edit, but the model won't conditionally validate those fields

Comment: I am passing a Child, and the Child class has a reference to Parent, in the original example. Thus validation fails unless Parent has all of Parent's required fields, even though they are not needed to select any particular parent for the child that is being edited.

Comment: But why does your Child model has a Parent when you are editing only a child? Why are you passing your domain entities to your views? Why aren't you using view models? Like this: `ChildViewModel` in which you would include only what's necessary for the given view. All your problems come from the fact that you are not using view models: and believe me: validation is the smallest thing you will struggle with if you continue passing your domain entities to your views.

Comment: A few comments: The relevant project has exceedingly simple models with a few members. And even with a view model, I'd rather not have 2-3 different flavors of the same model with slightly different validation, when I can define all of the validation rules in a single class.

Comment: That's not an excuse for not using view models. There is never an excuse. Yes, you can define all the validation rules into a single class, except that, ... problems occur with this as you have already noticed. And as I said in my previous comment: I can tell you from my experience that this will be the smallest problem you will encounter. There will be much worse things later.

Comment: I guess I don't get it. Lets use a real example: I have a ClientType Model with 4 string properties -- each of these is persisted in all relevant views, with no additional data beyond validation tags. What do you gain by making a second view that is identical and contains the same properties?

Comment: You have a view model which is specific to the given view. But I won't insist anymore. You can do whatever you want. I have already thrown my 2¢.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override [ValidationAttribute.IsValid Method (Object, ValidationContext)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd730022)

```
protected virtual ValidationResult IsValid(
    Object value,
    ValidationContext validationContext
)
```

And access members of [ValidationContext Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382177)

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm! That significantly reduces the number of models I need to create.

Comment: Although this helps you, I completely agree with @Darin Dimitrov and strongly suggest you to use view models instead of domain entities in presentation layer. Things get much simpler that way